# Does the angle of colission affects the transference of linear momentum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, molecules

If we have a cubic container and then put in there some quantity of hydrogen molecules (10$^{22}$ molecules) an then all of them collide at the same time with a rigid wall of the cube, if them collide at 90° in one case an 45° in another, in which case the molecules transfer more  quantity of linear momentum?

Comment: In which case is the component of each molecule's velocity that is perpendicular to the wall greater ?

Comment: Thanks, now my problem is how I can calculate the momentum? Sorry if I ask this, but I don't have any idea in this topic, I mean, I barely know how to calculate the momentum of one particle, but how I can calculate the quantity of momentum that a bunch of particles transfer to a wall in a collision. Is just weird to me, I'm just a kid, I find this problem in a paper that some guy left in the street